# Paging issue with subreport in RDLC report

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I am working on a project where I am using RDLC report, I want to use a master report for header and footer that contains some company informations and it binds with different dataset and inside the main body of the report i have a subreport to show reports contents, this subreport is filled with different datasets for different reports.

Everything is working fine but when there are more records in the subreport then it divides into paging and when I click on the next page then its not working and show the first page again.

Infacat I have missed a technique but I am unable to identify it.

My code to bind the reports is below:

```
private void LoadReport()
{
    var objAccess = new DataAccess();
    _dataSet = objAccess.CompanyGetAll(); 
    var mainReport = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/ComanyInfo.rdlc"));
    ReportViewerTraineePayments.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(mainReport);
    ReportViewerTraineePayments.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    ReportViewerTraineePayments.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DS_CompanyInfo", _dataSet.Tables[0]));

    var subReport = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(DynamicReportName));
    ReportViewerTraineePayments.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing +=
        new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(localReport_SubreportProcessing);
    ReportViewerTraineePayments.LocalReport.LoadSubreportDefinition("Rpt_Content", subReport);
}

private void localReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(DynamicDataSetName, DynamicReportDataSource.Tables[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it my self by setting `AsyncRendering="True"`
and

> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>           if (!IsPostBack)
>           {
>               LoadReport(); 
>           }
>       }